# print later time using loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I want to print a list of time (hour) but filter out earlier time. For example now is 12 PM, in the list I want to hide hours that's earlier than 12 PM.

I stuck at here

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
                var ampm = (hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
                var datetime = hours + ":" + d.getMinutes() + " " + ampm;

                console.log(datetime);

                var firstAm = '<li>12:00 AM</li>';
                $('.holder').append(firstAm);
                for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
                    var am = '<li>' + i + ':00 AM</li>';
                    $('.holder').append(am);
                }

                var firstPm = '<li>12:00 PM</li>';
                $('.holder').append(firstPm);
                for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
                    var pm = '<li>' + i + ':00 PM</li>';
                    $('.holder').append(pm);
                }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29615mLb/

Comment: I believe you do not need to *hide*. Just start your list with the current hour.

Comment: @PM77-1 what do u mean by hide?

Comment: You state: "*I want to hide hours that's earlier than 12 PM.*" And you tag your question with `jQuery`. So I assumed you meant `hide()`.

Comment: @PM77-1 not in this context lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```js
var d = new Date(),
  t;
for (var i = d.getHours() + 1; i <= 24; i++) {
  t = i % 12;
  t = t == 0 ? 12 : t;
  $('.holder').append('<li>' + t + ':00 ' + (i < 12 || i == 24 ? 'AM' : 'PM') + '</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="holder"></p>
```

---

Another way is

```js
var d = new Date(),
  till = new Date(),
  t, h, m;

d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 30 - d.getMinutes() % 30, 0, 0);
till.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
till.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

while (d <= till) {
  h = d.getHours();
  m = d.getMinutes();
  t = h % 12;
  t = t == 0 ? 12 : t;
  $('.holder').append('<li>' + (t < 10 ? '0' : '') + t + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m + ' ' + (h < 12 || h == 24 ? 'AM' : 'PM') + '</li>');
  d.setMinutes(m + 30)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="holder"></p>
```

Comment: 12:00 AM
1:00 PM
2:00 PM
3:00 PM
4:00 PM

why I'm seeing 12AM appear as the first result?

Comment: This is awsome but is this flexible? what if I want to add 30 min? user can select 12:30 if now it's 12:00.

Comment: thanks so much! so the param is just the last line?  d.setMinutes(m + 15) ?

Comment: @JamesLemon also `d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 30 - d.getMinutes() % 30, 0, 0);`

Comment: Thanks so much! You are the most helpful guy in this site!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the correct time in the evening, try adding the following line before you define datetime.

```
var hours = (hours % 12 !== 0) ? (hours % 12) : 12;
var datetime = hours + ":" + d.getMinutes() + " " + ampm;
```